# Eclipse JDT - Highlight multiple text ranges in editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-jdt

I want to highlight multiple text ranges in the editor. I tried using selectAndReveal(offset,length) method defined in ITextEditor. But it only works for a single text range.

```
final IJavaElement create = JavaCore.create(handle);      

try {
      ITextEditor editor = (ITextEditor) JavaUI.openInEditor(create);
      editor.selectAndReveal(5, 150);                            
} catch (final Exception e) {
       Logs.logError();
}
```

**EDIT**
It only allows single range highlighting. What I want is multiple range styling to differentiate some text fragments.

Answer (score 0):

The text editors use the `StyledText` control which does not support highlighting multiple ranges.

You might be able to use JFace Annotations: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Feditors_annotations.htm

Comment: Hi, I think there should be a mechanism for doing multiple highlights. For example when I select a variable identifier in editor, it usually highlights the places in which that particular variable is used.

Comment: The one you select is highlighted any others that are visible are shown differently and are not highlights (either styles or annotations not sure which).

Comment: oh oh, yes you are correct, I will look in to that, i was on the wrong track, changing styles of particular ranges is what I need. Thanks